# Facebook shared image from external website too small despite being correct size

Tags: facebook, image, share, thumbnails, sharing

I'm working on an external client's project.

There is a share button for Facebook that works fine. I have created the shared image to be 1200 x 630 so it should display as a rectangular image in the newsfeed when shared.

However, despite the image being this size Facebook still shares the thumbnail as the small square icon and also as a result crops the image incorrectly. Therefore rather than get a rectangular shared image on the newsfeed I get a small, square image that also crops my original rectangular designed image.

I've read a few posts about this, however, all answers were regarding the image size... I'm a bit out of ideas. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use meta tags to explicitly set the widht and height of the image

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://yourwebsite.com/images/yourimage.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:image:width" content="500" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="500" />
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However, I have no control over the <head> of the document which is where this code would go. Only have control over the <body> elements and so far have worked the code via an iframe... not ideal I know but unfortunately the only way that's been able to partially work so far.